# Nested NavigationLink selection bound to ObservedObject: Navigation animation shown twice

Tags: ios, swiftui, binding, state, observedobject

I have a List of NavigationLinks (2nd level) with their selection bound to an @ObservedObject's value, so I can navigate programmatically by setting `stuff.selectedMessage`.

```
struct MessagesView: View {

  @ObservedObject var stuff: MyStuff

  var body: some View {

      List {
        ForEach(stuff.myMessages!) { myMessage in
          NavigationLink(
            destination: MyMessageView(myMessage: myMessage),
            tag: String(myMessage.MessageID),
            selection: $stuff.selectedMessage) {
              Text(myMessage.text)
          }
        }
      }

  }
}

struct ContentView: View {

  @ObservedObject var stuff = MyStuff.shared
   
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        NavigationLink(
          destination: MessagesView(stuff: stuff),
          tag: "view-messages",
          selection: $stuff.selectedView) {
            // ...
        }
        NavigationLink(
          destination: SomeOtherView(stuff: stuff),
          tag: "view-other",
          selection: $stuff.selectedView) {
            // ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


class MyStuff: ObservableObject {

  static let shared = MyStuff()

  @Published var selectedView: String? = nil
  @Published var selectedMessage: String? = nil
  // ...

}
```

When tapping on a NavigationLink or when I set `stuff.selectedMessage` programmatically, it navigates to the corresponding view, however, it seems like the navigation is done twice, or at least **the navigation animation is shown twice**, which doesn't look nice (probably because it's 2nd level).

When using a `@State` variable instead of `@ObservedObject` it works fine. However, I need to access `stuff` from AppDelegate (when receiving a "New Message" push notification) and it seems I cannot  (or shouldn't) access @State variables from AppDelegate.

When not using nested navigation, it also works fine.

**Edit: It also works fine when removing the `selection` parameter of the root NavigationLinks.**

Xcode version: 13.2.1

Comment: Try using `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject`.